# adding ticks to matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

In the following simple code:

```
dat = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,4)*np.ones((4,1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(dat, interpolation='none')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

I want the colorbar to have the range [0,1]. This can be accomplished by:

```
dat = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,4)*np.ones((4,1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(dat, interpolation='none')
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
cbar.set_clim(0, 1)
cbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(0,1,11))
plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

Clearly the range was changed as the colors have become lighter, but the ticks have not changed, i.e. `cbar.set_ticks()` doesn't perform as expected. How can i change the tick marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the colorbar does not adjust, but you can achieve what you want by changing your call to `imshow` like so

```
dat = np.linspace(0.1, 0.9, 4) * np.ones((4,1))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(dat, interpolation='none', vmin=0, vmax=1)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
plt.show()
```

Note the additional `vmin` and `vmax` arguments.

Comment: ahh that is much easier than separate calls to `cbar.set_clim()` and `cbar.set_ticks()`, thx...

Comment: There should be notifiers inplace to update the color bar when the limits on the colormappable change...

Comment: In the OP it seems that the requirements are (1) to be able to adjust the range of the colorbar and (2) to be able to adjust the ticks within the color bar.  While this answer addresses requirement (1), we can accomplish requirement (2) by also including `cbar.set_ticks` from the OP. Also, does `vmax=0` need to be changed to `vmax=1` to match the OP?